# Any way to cause a refresh of selectedItemReminder in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, comboboxmodel

I have a JComboBox with a custom model which extends DefaultComboBoxModel.

When I want to add an item to my combo box I add it to the model and repaint the JComboBox. However, this is leaving the internal field:

```
selectedItemReminder
```

unchanged. What should I be doing instead.

Comment: What does `selectedItemReminder` actually do?

Comment: It seems to keep a cache in the JComboBox itself so when setSelectedItem is called it doesn't call the model if the value it is being set to is the value of selectedItemReminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what it is you are trying to achieve, but I might be temptered to modify the method to read more like...

```
private void setChildren(Collection<BoundedArea> children) {
    int oldSize = getSize();
    // Notify the listeners that the all the values have begin removed
    fireIntervalRemoved(this, 0, oldSize - 1);
    this.children.clear();
    for (BoundedArea boundedArea : children) {
        if (boundedArea.getBoundedAreaType() == childType) {
            this.children.add(boundedArea);
        }
    }
    int size = getSize();
    // Notify the listeners that a bunch of new values have begin added...
    fireIntervalAdded(this, 0, size - 1);
    setSelectedItem(null);
}
```

The other issue I can see is you seem to be thinking that the list is `1` based, it's not, it's `0` based, that is, the first element is `0`

**Updated based on changes to the question**

From what I can understand, `intervalAdded` and `contentsChanged` of the `JComboBox` check to see if the selected value in the combo box model has changed, if it has, it calls `selectedItemChanged` which fires appropriate events to signal the change of the selected item...

I would, when you change the model, set the currently selected item value to something like `null` BEFORE you fire any event notifications...

So, using the previous example, I would do something more like...

```
private void setChildren(Collection<BoundedArea> children) {
    setSelectedItem(null);
    int oldSize = getSize();
    // Notify the listeners that the all the values have begin removed
    fireIntervalRemoved(this, 0, oldSize - 1);
    this.children.clear();
    for (BoundedArea boundedArea : children) {
        if (boundedArea.getBoundedAreaType() == childType) {
            this.children.add(boundedArea);
        }
    }
    int size = getSize();
    // Notify the listeners that a bunch of new values have begin added...
    fireIntervalAdded(this, 0, size - 1);
}
```

Comment: This would be neater however, I have now rewritten the question as I understand the problem better.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Also worth noting that in DefaultComboBoxModel after a set value it calls 
     fireContentsChanged(this, -1, -1);